# Service Layer and Entities in Yii 2

Tags: php, spring, yii2

I've been learning Yii2 framework for a couple of weeks now. One of its core concepts is "Fat models, thin controllers". Reading the source code of the [advanced application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) I found that due to this concept nearly all the logic is contained within the models.

Well, there could be no questions at all if I hadn't some experience with Spring MVC where service layer seems to be a kind of natural way to decouple application's logic from its actual data.

So the question is: can it be a good practice to implement such an enterprise-like structure in an application built with Yii2? Speaking more specifically: is it worth breaking Yii's models into Entities, DTOs and Services?

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: The question can seem to be a kind of too abstract or subjective but having little experience with Yii2 I'd like to know are there any architectural features in Yii2 that could make the above mentioned implementation be not optimal in regard to code maintenance, performance and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create models that are not ActiveRecords, so they actually become your service layer, just need to extend from `yii\base\Model` or `yii\base\Object` as you see fit, and implement all the logic you need there. You can also create those models on another folder called services, so their namespace would become `app\services\ModelName`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your answer resembles what I was mulling over. What could you tell about the following: create some DTOs extending from `yii\base\Model` with purpose to transfer and validate data from client (from forms), create some Entities extending from `yii\db\ActiveRecord` with purpose to persist validated data and create some Services extending from `yii\base\Component` in order to implement all the business logic so that Entities and DTOs were concerned with their specific purposes only?

Comment: I think that would be a really good way to divide and organize all the application logic. Even the default basic app template does something similar, using both LoginForm and User for the login process, separating the validation of username and password for login from the User model. The best thing about Yii2 is the fact that it doesn't limit what you can do, it's more like a set of tools ready to be used, but you can still create your own tool using them as a base.

Comment: In some of my own projects, i make a distinction between data models, search models and form models (when needed), that way i don't end up with a 1000+ lines model (although sometimes i still do)

Answer (score 0):

Using another feature instead of built-in feature can not be a good practice for every framework.

IMO, the model part is a killer feature of yii2, so if you do not need scaffold (code generation), you can use any other php framework without model part ([zf2](http://framework.zend.com/), [symfony2](https://symfony.com/), micro-frameworks).

So you can use your own model architecture without any perfomance lag but you'll need to write more code to make things done and your models will be hard to support by other people that are using yii2 and therefore I recommend to use another framework which comes without model layer.